# Express.js How to get data fromArray after Database call?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to loop through my Database obj and push it to an array so i can Download the files in one zip. The Problem is after the loop the response of the "newarr" is empty.

Is it because the response is loaded before the loop finished? And if so how can i get it working?

Totally new to nodejs and async await Function.

```
router.get('/customzip/:data', userMiddleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  const arr = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
  
  const newarr = [];

  arr.array.forEach( e => {
    if(e.type === 'folder'){
        db.query(`SELECT * FROM files fil JOIN folders f ON f.folder_id = fil.folder_id WHERE fil.folder_id = ${db.escape(e.id)}`, (err, obj) => {
          if(err){
            return res
            .status(500)
            .send({
              msg: err
            });
          }

          Object
          .keys(obj)
          .forEach( function (item, index) {
            const path = obj[item].file_dir.toString();
            const pseudoobj = {};
            pseudoobj['path'] = path;
            pseudoobj['name'] = obj[item].file_name + '.' + obj[item].file_type;
            newarr.push(pseudoobj);
            // res.zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip'); // returning array
          });
          // res.zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip'); // not returning array
        });
    }
  });
  res.zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip');
});
```

Comment: What library are you using to provide zip functionality to the Express response object?

Comment: My guess is that your loop is taking longer to finishes and because the loop is non blocking your res.zip is called before the loop is done. 

You should look at putting the loop in a promise to resolve once the loop is complete to ensure you have the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume this will do the trick

```js
const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array)
  }
}

router.get('/customzip/:data', userMiddleware.isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const arr = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
    const newarr = [];
    await asyncForEach(arr.array, await e => {
      if (e.type === 'folder') {
        const obj = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM files fil JOIN folders f ON f.folder_id = fil.folder_id WHERE fil.folder_id = ${db.escape(e.id)}`)
        Object.keys(obj).map((item, index) => {
          const path = obj[item].file_dir.toString();
          const pseudoobj = {};
          pseudoobj['path'] = path;
          pseudoobj['name'] = obj[item].file_name + '.' + obj[item].file_type;
          newarr.push(pseudoobj);
          // res.zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip'); // returning array
        });
        // res.zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip'); // not returning array
      }
    })

    // console.log the new array to make sure this is what you want
    console.log(newarr)
  
    res.status(200).zip(newarr, 'download_' + Date.now() + '.zip');
  } catch (msg) {
    res.status(500).send({ msg })
  }
});
```

basically, you are looping over your database which is an async action. You are passing a callback function into the database call and executing code but since its an async function the code keeps on running and returns an empty array because its not done running yet. using await on a promise tells the request loop to continue handling other things in the app and pickup at this spot again when the promise is complete, and then resume the rest of the function.

also, because you are trying to trigger MULTIPLE asynchronous calls, you want to loop over them synchronously without blocking the request loop, which is why i added the asyncForEach function